# Can I add a second junction box to house a doorbell transformer?

Tags: electrical, wiring, junction-box

In the attic I have electricity running out to a junction box.  The wire in the junction box connects 2 things.  The first one is that it brings power down to a light switch.  There's a NM cable coming back up to the attic over the the light.

However recently I added a transformer to the junction box to power up my Ring Doorbell (white to white, green to green, and black to black).  I didn't notice this until today that my Ring Doorbell doesn't actually get direct power unless I flip the switch to the light.

I want to ask if I could just add another junction box next to the one I already have so that I would have a dedicated box supplying power to my transformer and doorbell.

So here's what I imagine. First the line power would come to junction box 1.  In junction box 1, I would attach the transformer for the doorbell.  I would also have another NM cable to bring electricity to junction 2.  In junction 2, that's where I would reconnect to the NM cable that goes down to the light switch.

I don't know if this will work.  Or is there another way where I can keep the first arrangement and be able to tap power directly from the junction box without the light switch controlling my transformer.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: Depending on your jurisdiction, junction boxes, if used as you describe, are not allowed. I had to have one removed and some moderate rewiring done before I could get HO insurance. Anyway you're not able pull a new wire from the main, to the switch, to the light, and add another outlet for the transformer?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the transformer wired on the switch loop so the switch position makes a difference. If you move the door bell to the light feeder it will work as it should. Can you add another box and provide a dedicated circuit? Yes, but this would be quite expensive and really not needed for such a small load.